# Tweepy Streamlistener string length

Tags: python, twitter, stream, listener, tweepy

I am working on a python app which uses tweepy to track the twitter stream for certain strings (using the Streamlistener feature). However, it seems that I always run into a 406 status code from twitter api and I think this is because the string I am trying to track is quite long.

I've searched for an indication of whether there is a limit to the length of the string that I am tracking, is anyone aware of this and can confirm the string length limit?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you disclose which word or string you are trying to track ?

Comment: Of course, here is a sample of a string that I want to track: "We want to save the animals that are in danger and almost extinct. Please retweet to sign up and help."

Comment: See I don't guess if it allows space separated keywords, as you will notice that if you want to create the #Hashtag, then you cannot put a space between them, try using a single, most relevant keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Well.. After some digging and digging, I came across this: https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview/request-parameters#track

where it states the following: "Each phrase must be between 1 and 60 bytes, inclusive."

I wish this was written in bold with caps lock on!

Anyways, for those that missed it like I did, here ya go.